# ViewBinding Null Exception Error in Fragment after reopen the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to ask something. I used viewbinding inside fragment and navigation component to navigate fragment.

This is the case

(First Task)
From Activity A (There is no fragment) -> Activity B (Fragment A)
and do some process. after that i finish Activity B.

And then now I'm in Activity A. The problem is, when I do same task like that

(Second Task)
Activity A -> Activity B (Fragment A)
and do some process in fragment A, i got null view binding.

Can you give me solution for this error? i can't solve it
Thanks before

Here my code in Fragment A

```
private var _binding : FragmentOrderBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

.....

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentOrderBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val mapsView = binding?.root?.findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.maps_view)
    markerViewAdapter = MarkerViewAdapter(mapsView!!)
    return binding?.root
}

......

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Comment: Please share your exception log!

Comment: sorry for that @miladsalimi i forget to attach the log exception. But idk why the problem is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in Google :

Your implementation is just like Google.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

So my suggestion is :

**Build -> Clean project**

Otherwise you can share `exception` logs too.

Comment: Fragments outlive their views. Make sure you clean up any references to the binding class instance in the fragment's onDestroyView() method. `override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}` 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#kotlin

Comment: The point you made at the end is also wrong. From what source do you make this point? `onViewCreated` Called immediately after `onCreateView` has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Thanks for your attention dear @AlirezaNoorali , i was in bad mode when i wrote that

Answer (score 1):

Try move markerViewAdapter into `onViewCreate`.

Or use view binding delegate library for handle view binding, many available on github.